# Is it possible to assign a "classpath" and apply a plugin for only one flavor of my app?

Tags: android, android-studio

Using Android Studio, I created an app with two flavors. Here are the flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors{
    publicVersion{
        dimension "default"
    }
    promoVersion{
        dimension "default"
    }
}
```

I know how to add dependencies for only one flavor, just add the flavor name before *Implementation*. For example `promoVersionImplementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'`

However there are other things that I want to be flavor specific too.
In the project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8' //--> I want this to be applied only to the promoVersion flavor
    }
}
```

And in the app gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' //--> I want this to be applied only to the promoVersion flavor
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you find how to make `classpath` as flavor-specific inside the project's `gradle` file?

Comment: I don't even remember what project this was for :)

Comment: @malhobayyeb did you find any solutions for the classpath problem?

Comment: @amira no I didn’t

Answer (score -1):

For the app's gradle file you can do the following:

```
flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors{
    publicVersion{
        dimension "default"
    }
    promoVersion{
        dimension "default"
        plugins {
           id 'com.google.gms.google-services' //--> I want this to be applied only to the promoVersion flavor
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what about the classpath?